# Almacenar array en base de datos MySQL y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, array, mysqli

Tengo una tabla de base de datos donde entre otras cosas necesito almacenar un dato para cada día del mes (que refleja los ingresos obtenidos ese día).

Todas las cantidades de todos los días del mes (31 días que son reiniciados al final del mes) necesito almacenarlas en una sola columna, y he pensado que la mejor forma de hacerlo es almacenando un `Array` que luego pueda devolver y usar sin ningún problema.

Mi pregunta es, ¿**cómo puedo almacenar un Array de PHP en una base de datos**? y ¿**Qué hago para recuperarlo desde la base de datos de nuevo como otro Array de PHP**?

La pregunta excluye cómo hacer el `INSERT` y el `SELECT`, tan solo necesito saber cómo transformar y recuperar el array.

Comment: puedes separar los datos separados por coma o algún caracter y luego hacer un split para convertirlos nuevamente en array

Comment: ¿Por qué un array? Los puedes insertar separados por coma y si quieres un array al sacarlos lo creas con [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)... Hacer lo que quieres es intentar meter dentro de la base de datos algo que pertenece **a la lógica del lenguaje de programación**. Se puede hacer, pero no es lógico, ni útil, ni práctico. Cada cosa para cada cosa. Dados los valores: `1,25,33,48...` ingresados en la columna `valores`  de la tabla. Traes el valor de la columna: `$mValores=explode(","$row["valores"]);` y ya tienes en `$mValores` un array.

Comment: @A.Cedano Cierto, eso ocupará menos espacio y es más rápido. Utilizaré ese método.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes insertar los datos dentro de una columna normal, del tipo `VARCHAR` será suficiente si es una lista de números, o del tipo `TEXT` si fueran datos más grandes (quizá en ese caso habría que pensar en normalizar la tabla).

Luego, por programación puedes traer los datos y crear un array con `explode`.

Supongamos que esta es tu lista de valores:

```
# $row["valores"]=$mValues; #valores es tu columna de valores separados por coma
$mValues="12,8,-1,80,99,157,77,22";
$arrValues=explode(",",$mValues);

#Prueba
print_r($arrValues);
```

Salida de la prueba:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 8
    [2] => -1
    [3] => 80
    [4] => 99
    [5] => 157
    [6] => 77
    [7] => 22
)
```

Si por algún motivo necesitaras saber a qué día corresponde cada dato, por lo único que debes preocuparte es por crear la lista de valores debidamente ordenada, luego, para buscar tienes que restar `1` al valor del día que necesites,  ya que, como se ve en la salida PHP crea los arrays indexando a partir de `0`.

Digamos que necesitas el dato del día 5 del mes, ese dato está realmente en el índice `4` de array.

```
$dia=5;
echo $arrValues[$dia-1];
```

Salida:

```
99
```

*That's all folks!*

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo que hago en esos casos es insertar los datos con [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) y después al leerlos de base de datos los recupero con [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php).

Te pongo un ejemplo, **muy básico**, de la clase donde utilizo este método. 
En este pequeño ejemplo, los campos `cosa1`, `cosa2`y `cosa3` serán campos con estas características.

```
class clausulas extends db {

    protected $tableName = 'clausulas';
    protected $orden_defecto = 'descripcion';
    protected $id_empresa = null;

    public function __construct($id_empresa) {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->id_empresa = $id_empresa;        
    }

    public function get($id) {
        if ($instance = parent::get($id)) {
            $instance->cosa1 = json_decode($instance->cosa1);
            $instance->cosa2 = json_decode($instance->cosa2);
            $instance->cosa3 = json_decode($instance->cosa3);
            return $instance;
        }
    }

    public function save($registro) {

        if (isset($registro->cosa1)) {
            $registro->cosa1 = $this->json_encode($registro->cosa1);
        }

        if (isset($registro->cosa2)) {
            $registro->cosa2 = $this->json_encode($registro->cosa2);
        }

        if (isset($registro->cosa3)) {
            $registro->cosa3 = $this->json_encode($registro->cosa3);
        }

        parent::save($registro);
      }

    }
```

De esta forma, con `$clausulas->get($id)` obtengo un registro del cual ya tengo los campos decodificados y con `$clausulas->save($instancia)` ya se almacenan debidamente formateados.

He utilizado esto en uno de mis últimos proyectos y los resultados son muy satisfactorios, eso sí, son campos sobre los cuales no se harán referencias cruzadas de otras tablas ni ningún tipo de acción (agrupación, ordenación...) sobre esos campos más que su lectura y posterior procesado en PHP.
Lo bueno, además, es que esto me permite que unos registros tengan datos que otros no van a tener, en tu caso tendrás meses de diferentes número de días.

Explorando este método, he visto que mysql tiene ahora un tipo de dato que se llama [json](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) pero como yo uso MariaDB y no lo implementa me quedo con mi pequeña aproximación.

Creo que esta es la forma más sencilla y versátil de realizar lo que comentas, mejor que *parsearlo* con otro formato arbitrario.

**NOTA**

Verás que utilizo `$this->json_encode()`, eso lo hice por si en un futuro necesito hacer algo más que un mero `json_encode()`, así ya tengo la clase prepara usando un método propio.

**NOTA 2**

Por aclarar, yo lo que almaceno realmente en esos campos son arrays multidimensionales y arrays de objetos, quizá para datos más simples (arrays unidimensionales) seria conveniente otro tipo de parseado más sencillo.
Eso ya queda al gusto del consumidor ;)